# Better Method of Creating Multi Line Text Entry?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, multiline, tkinter-entry

I need to create a message box for a user in a GUI with tkinter. For 3/4 of my entries, `Entry(master, options. . .,)` works. But for a message box, I need a multi line entry.

How would I do this? I tried `ScrolledText(root).pack()`, but it doesn't have the same commands/variables as Entry.

Answer (score 1):

It is not explicitly mentioned in the [documentation](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-scrollbar-patterns.htm), but even if the [`tkinter.Entry`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm) widget's content can be scrolled, it **can only be scrolled horizontally** meaning that you can not use the `yscrollcommand`option unlike with  `Canvas`, `Text` and `Listbox` widgets.

This means technically your goal is not feasible, I mean you can not write multiple lines inside an Entry widget so that you scroll them vertically but only horizontally:

[image]

(if you need the code of this screenshot, please let me know).

Answer (score 1):

Billal is right, however i would recomend simply using a Textbox.

go to:  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_text.htm

for more information